# Sumproduct add up and divide by

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

See Sumproduct formulas below. Result of nb. 1 = 6890 & nb. 2 = 8201. I want to  divide nb. 1 by 2, result in % should be 84%. However, if I combine the formulas (see nb. 3) it results in 100% instead of 84%. How can I add up two sumproduct formulas and divide them by another added up sumproduct?

1. `=SUMPRODUCT((Doli_Dt>=$C$9)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$10)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="Answered < 20s")*(Doli_db))+SUMPRODUCT((SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$8)*(SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED")*(SF_CALLS_ANSWERED_20sec="OK"))`
2. `=SUMPRODUCT((Doli_Dt>=$C$9)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$10)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="answered")*(Doli_db))+SUMPRODUCT((SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$8)*(SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED"))`
3. `=IFERROR(ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(((Doli_Dt>=$C$9)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$10)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="Answered < 20s")*(Doli_db))+SOMMEPROD((SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$8)*(SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED")*(SF_CALLS_ANSWERED_20sec="OK")))/SUMPRODUCT(((Doli_Dt>=$C$9)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$10)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="answered")*(Doli_db))+SUMPRODUCT((SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$8)*(SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED"))),2),"-")`

Comment: Add some sample data to test the command to fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

@Rajesh S: Already found the solution, see formula below. Solved by adding and removing some brackets at the right place (especially before SUMPRODUCT).

```
=IFERROR(ROUND((SUMPRODUCT((Doli_Dt>=$C$7)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$8)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="Answered < 20s")*(Doli_db))+(SUMPRODUCT((SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED")*(SF_CALLS_ANSWERED_20sec="OK")*(SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$6))))/(SUMPRODUCT((Doli_Dt>=$C$7)*(Doli_Dt<=$C$8)*(Doli_Act="Phone")*(Doli_Stat="answered")*(Doli_db))+(SUMPRODUCT((SF_CALLS_STATUS="ANSWERED")*(SF_CALLS_WEEK=$B$6)))),2),"")
```

Comment: To justify the Formula please edit the post and add some sample data !